# Easiest way to create a graphical representation of Application Usage Report?

Tags: applications, ms-office, remote-desktop

[image]I have several mac users who claim they need all 3 major browsers for testing websites and they need Admin privileges to keep them updated. (My Company doesn't support but Safari.)

I have run an Application Usage report for the last year on these users to pull what applications where used, how long, etc etc..

I have the data in Excel and I am trying to 'pie' chart the data so I can see what application they are really using the most. I have already split each user up into individual sheets. Has anyone else solved this problem (using Excel or even another tool)?

Comment: This is solidly on topic as you have a clear, practical problem that relates to using Mac hardware and software. You might consider explicitly explaining what tool you used to generate the measurement data. Some people will have answers to get a different tool. Other answers will be how to use Excel to chart this. Yet others might know how to grab the data from the collector in a more malleable format (assuming you are using Apple's Remote Desktop to collect this data - it stores data in a SQLite database).

Comment: I exported the data from ARD. I the data in an Excel sheet. Just need assistance in parsing the data: what percent of  "Firefox" is used, what percent of "Word" is used, in the overall application data usage.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that you want to have a pie chart for each user, and you want to group by application, and by time spent with each, I would recommend using Excel to do so. In a nutshell:

1. Create a PivotChart for each user, with the data grouped as you prefer. In my exercise, I selected Application and Time. Highlight the columns, with the top row being the header, and select Insert | PivotChart. Check the fields to add to the report, in this case Application and Time.
2. You can configure your chart to your liking. I tend to add value labels to my pie chart slices.

You can see my crude, 5 minute example below.

[image: PieChart]